# onActivityResult in dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, start-activity, onactivityresult

I'm taking photo from dialog fragment. And also I need something like `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                getActivity();
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                    setPic();
                }
                break;
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
                getActivity();
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    handleBigCameraPhoto();

                }
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Bu this method is not being called. Are there any method like this which can be used in dialog fragment??

Comment: onActivityResult of fragment will not call directly, you have to call it from its parent activity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try like this :

to start activity from fragment :

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, code);
```

to get result back in fragment :

in your parent activity (fragment call activity) :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    fragmentObject
            .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Hey man i tried your solution but it is showing the error that Fragment is not attached to Activity.

Comment: in your parent activity (fragment call activity) : how to call fragment call activity ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is implement the hosting activity's `onActivityResult` and call its base class implementation like below...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

    //this makes sure the child fragments receive this event
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ...

}
```

You don't really need a reference to the fragment(s). Calling the activity's base class implementation will ensure all fragment's receive the call to `onActivityResult`