# startActivityForResult from within a DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to implement a dialog with a choice. Each choice will start an activity using `startActivityForResult` and the `DialogFragment` will handle the response using `onActivityResult`.

So far what I have is something like this:

```
class ChoiceFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setItems(sources, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SomeActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // This never gets called
    }
}
```

And in my activity, I'm starting the fragment like this:

```
ChoiceFragment frag = new ChoiceFragment();
frag.show(getFragmentManager(), "choices");
```

As you can see from the comment, `onActivityResult` is not being called.

I've seen this scenario mentioned in several questions, but they all seem to be assuming that the main activity was also calling `onActivityResult`, or that that the fragment was called `getActivity().startActivityForResult()`, neither of which are true in my case.

Comment: I think you forgot override `onActivityResult` in hosting activity.

Comment: But my hosting activity is not calling `onActivityResult` at all...

Comment: with `super.onActivityResult(...)` ?

Comment: Didn't I just say the hosting activity is _not_ calling `onActivityResult`?

Answer (score 2):

**ChoiceFragment.java :**

```
package com.example.AndroidTest;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @autor Sergey Shustikov
 */
class ChoiceFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private CharSequence[] sources = new CharSequence[]{"Second"};

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setItems(sources, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),SecondActivity.class);
                    getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("ResultA","This is choice");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.AndroidTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ChoiceFragment frag;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        frag = new ChoiceFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(frag,"choices");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("ResultA", "This is HostActivity");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            frag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java :**

```
package com.example.AndroidTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @autor Sergey Shustikov
 */
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557965/onactivityresult-in-dialog-fragment)!
This is the answer.